# Vuex data not saved with createPersistedState

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Im trying save my vuex state when page refreshes , I used createPersistedState but the data still disappear no matter what

my store file :

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";

import createPersistedState from "vuex-persistedstate";
import data from "../store/projectsData";

export default createStore({
  plugins: [createPersistedState()],
  modules: {
    data,
  },
});
```

ive tried createPersistedState package and vuex-persists but both dont work !

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the package like so:

```
plugins: [
    createPersistedState({ storage: window.sessionStorage })
]
```

However, I wouldn't recommend using this package because it's deprecated. You can manually achieve the desired purpose using [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), [localeStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), or [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) based on your needs.

Comment: Shouldn't help. It could be expected that it has a reasonable default, and it actually does